# Android, Parcelable and am I doing this correctly

Tags: android, parcelable

Ok, started my first Android project today and am kinda stuck.  I'd appreciate any help.

I have a class which is basically a list container for other classes. I have created an instance of this class in the main activity and was planning on passing it, or classes it contains, to other activities to be worked on.  Does this sound reasonable, or is it better to have a static and just call that from each activity?

My second point is, I have read that it is preferable to implement parcelable to package data. However, what if your class contains member variables which are non-primitive types?

```
`class MyClassList {
    private SomeClass _one;
    private AnotherClass _two;
}`
```

Must they implement parcelable also?  If so, this is fine for my own classes (although sounds like a pain to implement), but what of classes I have no code access to?

Apologies if any of this doesn't make sense, but hopefully you'll understand where I'm coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they have to be `Parcelable` too.

If the code you wrote above is your actuall class then it's not good it has to extend Parcelable.

If that's too much pain for you, you can make the class to extend [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
Which will make it static.
About which is better to use, each has it's own opinion.

Another option is to use `Serializable`, however there is a preformence loss in using that.

I would recommend extending Parcelablebecause that's the right way to do it, and once you get the hang of it, it's not that hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, if my class has a member variable of, say "Date", how can I parcel this if it doesn't itself implement Parcelable?